# Domain classes in grails

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, spring-security

How to make relationship between two domain classes in grails . I already have one domain class from the plugin (spring security plugin) and i want to link USER domain class from plugin to the Profile domain class . What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

See the [GORM documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html) for a good overview.  For a one-to-one relationship as I assume a profile would be, you could simply do the following:

```
class User {
    Profile profile
}

class Profile {
    // only needed if you need to refer to user from the Profile instance
    static belongsTo = [user:User] 
}
```